# Development environment with vagrant + chef/puppet/salt: how to deal with user specific credentials (e.g. github)?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, puppet, chef-recipe, vagrantfile

I want to create a dev environment with vagrant and friends to streamline the onboarding process for new devs. Found some awesome tutorials already.

What I don't understand is how to deal with user specific stuff. For example, within the Chef (or Puppet or Salt) setup I want to checkout repositories (from github). Since they are private, I need to know the users credentials. Same goes for `npm login` and presumably other stuff.

**What kind of approaches are there, to deal with user specific logins?**

Comment: vagrant can use your local ssh keys - so no need to store any other credentials (at least for github).

Comment: The guest system can inhere the ssh keys from the host system?

Comment: yes, that's right - but maybe doing the github related stuff on the guest system in a shared folder makes more sense ...

Comment: Sure, but I can use the ssh keys for the git clone from the host system. Which is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

One of the extensible points in vagrant's puppet implementation is the ability to inject custom facts into the puppet run. See the section "Custom Facts" in the [Vagrantfile Puppet Apply](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html) docs.

That leaves the question of how to supply those facts to the Vagrantfile. One way is to create a file (yaml, json, etc) in your project directory that includes user specific settings and read it into the Vagrantfile (it's, just ruby, after all). Make sure you add the user specific settings file to your source control's ignore list. I've never tried this plugin, but [nugrant](https://github.com/maoueh/nugrant) looks like it does a lot of this.

The above has the nasty side effect of leaving your passwords stored on your hard drive in a place where anyone on the team knows to look. If that is not acceptable, you can also make Vagrant prompt the user for passwords on the command line and use the entered value. Doesn't require storing passwords on your host machine, but does require re-entering them every time you use vagrant.